# Is there a way to run some code before a program crashes?

Tags: c++, windows, dll

Note: This is meant for windows, and I am using Visual Studio 2019 with C++17

I have been trying to make a dll that when injected into a program, can run some code before the program crashes. I have attempted using atexit, hooking onto exit using libMinHook, hooking onto abort using libMinHook, and hooking onto terminate using libMinHook, but it didn't work. I learned that when a program crashes it gets killed. Does anyone have any advice? (I've tried to find answers online but couldn't find any)

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Structured Exception Handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/about-structured-exception-handling). This should allow you to catch exceptions that would otherwise cause the application to crash.

Comment: Depends on the cause of the crash.   If the OS is signalling the program to force termination (e.g. because the program has been detected doing something it shouldn't) then the only way to do what you seek is to trap the signal.  Unfortunately, not all such signals can be caught//trapped by the program (i.e. the OS can terminate the program, and the program can't block being terminated).   If you are running the program in a debugger, you may be able to set a relevant watch point (e.g. to kick into the debugger when some variable changes) or a break point.

Comment: A application "crash" in Microsoft Windows is normally nothing else than an unhandled SEH exception. Therefore, the most logical thing to do is to handle such exceptions. If you are doing this in an injected DLL, then you probably can't use [frame-based SEH exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/frame-based-exception-handling), unless you have control of the application's threads. Therefore, [vectored SEH exception handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/vectored-exception-handling) seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a debugging shell for your program and insert error exit code where you are likely to have malfunctions.

Comment: sorry I wasn't that clear, I meant a dll injected into a program that I didn't make, so I can't just edit the program